# Tile native behavor in itemTemplate of LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8, itemtemplate, longlistselector

I want to create a LongListSelector with gridLayout=grid, in the itemTemplate I want to implement the native behavor of a tile (delete or pin the tile with a long press on it), help please

Comment: you will need Windows Phone Toolkit - Context Menu for example take a look of this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/05/19/windows-phone-toolkit-context-menu-getting-selected-item-within-a-long-list-selector.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that now I understand what do you need and you should take a look to [HubTile control](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/HubTile_in_Windows_Phone). There are [few projects](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-hubtile-in-depth-part1-key-concepts-and-api) that demonstrates how it work. Also there is [some video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3arHRVp-2w).